# I can't unlock bootloader on Nexus 7 (2013)

Tags: nexus-7, bootloader

Process reaches the stage of Erasing userdata add stops. I was waiting for 1 hour but nothing changes.
[image]

Comment: Did you accept the confirmation prompt on the Nexus 7's screen about unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: @DanHulme yes. after that nothing changes in cmd on PC and nexus provides no reaction for any pressed keys. i can only turn it off while keepind power button pressed for about 5 sec

Comment: Could you have knocked the USB cable loose when you did it? If you've tried more than once that would rule it out.

Comment: @DanHulme usb cable was accidentally disconnected when i tried to do it first time. can I solve this problem other way? or there are no variants and i can only throw my tablet away?

Comment: I tryed to turn off my nexus when it worked by keepind power button pressed. It turned off, but can't turn on. When I try to turn it on, there is only Google logo on screen as long as it stay turned on and android can't load. That's why I wanna unlock bootloader and reinstall android.